# Is there a way to get actual css-columns width and gap?

Tags: javascript, css

Is there a way to know actual column-width and column gap for CSS multi-column layout? Column-width property indicates the optimal column width. The actual column width may differ from the specified value: it may be wider when necessary to fill available space and narrow when the available space is too small.

```css
div {
  column-width: 200px;
  column-gap: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Atlantic trout snake mudhead ribbon eel, "ribbonfish pilot fish," sole dusky grouper. Fierasfer tiger shark central mudminnow viperfish, spotted danio sabertooth bat ray deepwater flathead thornyhead roosterfish, "pompano molly longfin escolar." Goldeye
  sandperch springfish, spiny dogfish chum salmon dogfish shark tiger barb escolar, "handfish Sundaland noodlefish," Rattail, knifefish Red salmon. Freshwater shark Blacksmelt eagle ray, bonytongue goldfish northern pike anemonefish molly loweye catfish
  stingray crocodile shark northern lampfish beluga sturgeon. Black mackerel denticle herring rough sculpin, perch, round herring Atlantic trout frilled shark mudsucker swordfish mahi-mahi. Shovelnose sturgeon sergeant major sheepshead catalufa pink salmon
  Jack Dempsey panga eel--sand stargazer ridgehead mosquitofish, "stonefish Antarctic icefish barreleye surfperch," mudskipper North American darter! Sábalo: scaleless black dragonfish Bitterling silver hake, spiny-back freshwater shark? Long-finned char
  kahawai, alligatorfish Modoc sucker scaleless black dragonfish New World rivuline. Grunion; daggertooth pike conger flat loach. Bonito, "yellow moray lionfish," sardine hammerhead shark.
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Maria1983/4Lokqxg2/12/

In this example, the actual column width is larger than the CSS column-width value.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are looking for :
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

```
  function getTheStyle(){
    var elem = document.getElementById("elem-container");
    var theCSSprop = window.getComputedStyle(elem,null).getPropertyValue("height");
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = theCSSprop;
   }
  getTheStyle();
```

Here is a jsfiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/sy9c8253/

Comment: getComputedStyle return column-width from css file too, not actual. I tested in chrome.

Comment: From MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/used_value. «Note: The getComputedStyle() DOM API returns the resolved value, which may either be the computed value or the used value, depending on the property.». I don't know if it is possible to get the "used value" for column-(width|gap).

Comment: I needed a reliable, straightforward way of setting the width of a DIV containing columns and so I set its column-gap to 0 in CSS and calculated everything with margins on the elements in the columns.  Column-gap was too "intelligent" to be of use to me.